# Finding $a, b\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{ax^2 + bx} - \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} = 1$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the values of real constants $a$ and $b$ such that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt{ax^2 + bx} - \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1} = 1$$

If I obtained $a = 1$  and $b=0$, is that the correct answer?

Or is $b$ actually some other value? If so, then why?

Comment: I've edited your question to include MathJax. Please ensure that it's correct.

Comment: Yup, the presentation is so much better now. However, can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: ok, by right, the entire limit to infinity encompasses the 2 surds. But I guess its okay. I can solve it now

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\dfrac{ax^2 + bx - x^2 - x - 1}{\sqrt{ax^2 + bx} + \sqrt{x^2 + x + 1}} = \dfrac{(a-1)x + (b-1) - \frac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{a + \frac{b}{x}} + \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}}}.$$

Comment: a = 1 and b = 3. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$